# nodejs pug render object

Tags: node.js, pug

Есть класс:

```js
class xlsxRow{
    
    constructor(name, articul, unit, quantity_ttk, quantity_fact, quantity_price_opt, unit_fact, name_db, percent, quantity_price_roz){
        //name2 = name;
        //this.name2 = name;
        this.name = name;
        this.articul = articul;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.quantity_ttk = quantity_ttk;
        this.quantity_fact = quantity_fact;
        this.quantity_price_opt = quantity_price_opt;
        this.unit_fact = unit_fact;
        this.name_db = name_db;
        this.percent = percent;
        this.quantity_price_roz = quantity_price_roz;    
    }
    
    getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    getArtucul(){
        return this.articul;
    }
    getUnit(){
        return this.unit;
    }
    getQuantityTtk(){
        return this.quantity_ttk;
    }
    getQuantityFact(){
        return this.quantity_fact;
    }
    getQuantityPriceOpt(){
        return this.quantity_price_opt;
    }
    getUnitFact(){
        return this.unitFact;
    }
    getNameDb(){
        return this.name_db;
    }
    getPercent(){
        return this.percent;
    }
    getQuantityPriceRoz(){
        return this.quantity_price_roz;
    }
    
    setName(name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    getArtucul(articul){
        this.articul = articul;
    }
    setUnit(unit){
        this.unit = unit;
    }
    setQuantityTtk(quantity_ttk){
        this.quantity_ttk = quantity_ttk;
    }
    setQuantityFact(quantity_fact){
        this.quantity_fact = quantity_fact;
    }
    setQuantityPriceOpt(quantity_price_opt){
        this.quantity_price_opt = quantity_price_opt;
    }
    setUnitFact(unitFact){
        this.unitFact = unitFact;
    }
    setNameDb(name_db){
        this.name_db = name_db;
    }
    setPercent(percent){
        this.percent = percent;
    }
    setQuantityPriceRoz(quantity_price_roz){
        this.quantity_price_roz = quantity_price_roz;
    }
    
}

module.exports = xlsxRow;
```

Есть шаблон:

```
html
head
    bode
        table(border=1)
            <tr><th>№</th><th>Наименование ТТК</th><th>Артикул</th><th>Ед. изм</th>
            <th>Количество ТТК</th><th>Факт</th><th>Цена опт.</th><th>Наименование</th>
            <th>%</th><th>Розница</th></tr>
                each n, index in rows
                    td=n // как здесь начать вытаскивать поля из класса
```

Есть роут:

```js
app.get('/simple2', (req, res) => {
    const table = XLSX.readFile('ex.xls');
    const sheet = table.Sheets[table.SheetNames[0]];

    const arrayData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(table.Sheets[table.SheetNames[0]], {header: 1, raw: false, cellText: true});

    let index_map = 0;
    var rows = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(arrayData[i][1], 10)) && parseInt(arrayData[i][2], 10) !== 2) {
            // из всех столбцов нам нужно только 6ть
                rows[++index_map] = new xlsxRow(arrayData[i][1],arrayData[i][2],arrayData[i][7],arrayData[i][8],parseInt(arrayData[i][23]),parseInt(arrayData[i][23]),arrayData[i][25].replace(',', ''),"пока что пусто",1.25,parseFloat(arrayData[i][25].replace(',', '')*1.25).toFixed(2));
        }
    }
    console.log(rows.size);
    res.render('index2', {'rows': rows});

});
```

Как мне в index2.pug вывести поля класса, что то вроде: n.getName() ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let rows = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 26; i++)
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(arrayData[i][1], 10)) && parseInt(arrayData[i][2], 10) !== 2)
                rows.push(new xlsxRow(arrayData[i][2],arrayData[i][7],arrayData[i][8],parseInt(arrayData[i][23]),parseInt(arrayData[i][23]),arrayData[i][25].replace(',', ''),"пока что пусто",1.25,parseFloat(arrayData[i][25].replace(',', '')*1.25).toFixed(2)));

    res.render('index', {
        rows: rows
    });
```

```
html
head
    bode
        table(border=1)
            <tr><th>№</th><th>Наименование ТТК</th><th>Артикул</th><th>Ед. изм</th>
            <th>Количество ТТК</th><th>Факт</th><th>Цена опт.</th><th>Наименование</th>
            <th>%</th><th>Розница</th></tr>
                each row, index in rows
                    tr(id='we' + index)
                        td(class='idposix' + index)=index
                        td(class='nametd' + index)=row.name
                        td(class='art' + index)=row.articul
                        td=row.unit
                        td(name='opt_size' id='opt_size' + index class='opt_size' +index)=row.quantity_ttk
                        td
                            input(type='text'
                                  name='my_size'
                                  id='my_size' + index
                                  class='my_size' +index
                                  value=row.quantity_fact)
                        td(class='opt_price' + index)=row.quantity_price_opt
                        td
                            input(type='text'
                                  name='currency'
                                  class='biginput'
                                  id='autocomplete' + index
                                  value=row.name)
                        td
                            input(type='text'
                                  name='c_percent'+ index
                                  class='c_percent'
                                  id='c_percent' + index
                                  value=row.percent)
                        td(name='r_price'
                            class='c_price'
                            id=r_price + index)=row.quantity_price_roz
```